# this.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I get an error with the following code:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(value) {
    return this.filter((element) => element != value); //TypeError: this.filter is not a function
}

([2, 3, 8, 9]).remove(3);
```

Can someone explain why? I do not get the same results when using a String function:

```
String.prototype.toTitleCase = function() {
    return this.replace(/\b\w+/g,
        (txt) => (txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase())
    ); // Works perfectly with no errors
}
```

I am using the latest version of Firefox (75.0, 64-bit)

Comment: What browser version?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a node.js 12.16 REPL and it worked as expected.  what runtime are you using?

Comment: @Taplar I am using the latest version of Firefox

Comment: @DanO I am using the latest version of Firefox

Comment: In jsfiddle for some reason the `this` is the `Window` object.

Comment: Works fine if you use an explicit `new Array()` and push to it before doing the remove call though

Comment: Changing it from Array.prototype.remove to Object.prototype.remove causes the `([])` form to work, which suggests that the `([])` version is not considered an instantiation of the Array class.

Comment: It's a missing semicolon.

Comment: Woah, nice catch on the duplicate.  I wouldn't have ever thought about that.

Comment: @Bergi of course its a semicolon, thank you!